# PHPUnit return "Data set #0 is invalid." with dataProvider

Tags: php, phpunit

This simple class return

> 1) Warning
>   The data provider specified for App\Tests\Twig\GenerateTokenTest::testGenerateToken is invalid.
>   Data set #0 is invalid.

```
class GenerateTokenTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider provideToken
     */
    public function testGenerateToken(int $length): void
    {
        $token = GenerateToken::generate($length);

        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }

    public function provideToken(): iterable
    {
        yield 8;
        yield 16;
        yield 29;
    }
}
```

Do you know why ?

Comment: Have you tried returning an array instead of a single int?

Comment: It's OK with array, I don't understand but it's OK, thanks :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use data providers for PhpUnit, they expect that an array of data is returned on each call. This inner array should match the input variables for your test method. So, if it has that single argument `$length`, the data provider should return an **array** containing the test input, like `yield [8];`

If the test method uses more than a single input variable - you've probably guessed it already: the array should contain more values. As an example, based on your code:

```
class GenerateTokenTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider provideToken
     */
    public function testGenerateToken(int $length, int $size): void
    {
        $token = GenerateToken::generate($length);

        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }

    public function provideToken(): iterable
    {
        yield [8, 9];
        yield [16, 17];
        yield [29, 30];
    }
}
```